# Jquery Unobtrusive validation not working on items after first in a View Model list - c# MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

So basically I have a form that has multiple "sections" in it that contain some user data. The user is able to select which sections they want to submit (there is a checkbox in each section to indicate this). The problem arises after the html has been rendered and the unobtrusive parser has run. It only populates the first section's input elements with the necessary data attributes needed for client side validation. I have included some stripped down code below.

Model:

```
public class EnrollmentFormViewModel
{
    public List<EnrollmentLocation> LocationList { get; set; }

    public EnrollmentFormViewModel()
    {
        LocationList = new List<EnrollmentLocation>();
    }

    public class EnrollmentLocation
    {
        [DisplayName("Enroll Location")]
        public bool EnrollLocation { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public EnrollmentLocation()
        {
            EnrollLocation = true;
            TStatList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
@using(@Html.BeginForm("EnrollUser", "EnrollUI"))
{        
    <div>
        @{ int count = 0;}
        @foreach (var station in Model.LocationList)
        {
            <div class="location form_new_row panel panel-primary">

                    <div id="info"class="form_half_width form_new_row">
                        <div id="first-name" class="q form_question form_half_width form_new_row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => station.FirstName, new { @class = "label-asterisk form_question_label" })
                            <div class="form_question_answer">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => station.FirstName, new { @class = "text_field", Name= count + "FirstName" })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => station.FirstName)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-info form_half_width">
                        <div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => station.EnrollLocation)@Html.LabelFor(m => station.EnrollLocation, new { @class = "form_question_label" })</div>
                    </div>
            </div> 

            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        <div class="form_new_row">
            <input type="submit" class="submit_button" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As I said earlier this populated the fields correctly and the first section looks fine. Here is a sample of an input element:

```
<input name="0FirstName" class="text_field valid" data-val="true" 
 data-val-required="Please enter your first name" 
 id="FirstName" type="text" value="nothing">
```

Any subsequent itmes however look like this:

```
<input name="1FirstName" class="text_field valid" id="FirstName" 
 type="text" value="nothing">
```

I have tried a couple of different things from other posts but nothing has worked. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Your overriding the `name` attribute! (and it wont post back correctly anyway). Construct you html in a `for` loop or use an editor template so the names are correct and can be matched up

Comment: I had switched the name to try to get the validation message divs to be looking at the correct input elements. Removing the name overload doesn't appear to fix the issue on my end however.

Comment: If you just removed your attempt to override the `name` attribute then you will be generating even more invalid html and duplicate name attributes. You need a `for` loop (e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.LocationList.Count; i++) {  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationList[i].FirstName) ....}` so the controls are correctly named with indexers (or use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `EnrollmentLocation`)

Comment: And not sure what you mean by the user can select a which sections to post back? - they will all post back (unless you have some javascript to disable and rename all the controls)

Comment: Sorry maybe it was a bit unclear. They will all be posted back but any section that doesn't have the EnrollLocation checkbox checked will just be ignored (and thus I don't need to worry about validation on the UI).

However the normal for loop does seem to have fixed the issue so thanks for the help.

Comment: Then you will need to apply a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar attribute so that client and server side validation is only applied when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Yup I already had those but simplified the code for this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to be iterating through that list using a for loop instead of a foreach.

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.LocationList.Count(); i++)
{
<div class="location form_new_row panel panel-primary">

    <div id="info" class="form_half_width form_new_row">
        <div id="first-name" class="q form_question form_half_width form_new_row">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.LocationList[i].FirstName, new { @class = "label-asterisk form_question_label" })
            <div class="form_question_answer">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.LocationList[i].FirstName, new { @class = "text_field", Name = count + "FirstName" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.LocationList[i].FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-info form_half_width">
        <div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.LocationList[i].EnrollLocation)@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.LocationList[i].EnrollLocation, new { @class = "form_question_label" })</div>
    </div>
</div>

{
    count++;
}
}
```

This will generate unique id values for each property on each Location.
E.G. LocationList[0].FirstName will be the id of the first element while LocationList[1].FirstName will be the name of the second.